# Unable to connect aws RDS to django local

Tags: django, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect my local django application to amazon RDS (tried with both MySQL and PostgreSQL) but I am not able to connect as it shows the following errors, Currently seeking answer for PostgreSQL.

In my **Settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USERNAME': 'my_username',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': 'database-abc.xxx.us-region-yyy.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

In AWS database configuration:

[image]

I get this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
> Is the server running on host "database-abc.xxx.us-region-yyy.rds.amazonaws.com" (69.420.00.121) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I referred to all the available data but still am unable to resolve this issue!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are security groups on your RDS?

Comment: open port 5432 (for postgres) in your security group.

Comment: @Marcin My security group on rds is default VPC security group

Comment: What are the inbound rules?

Comment: Inbound Rules type is all traffic by default and source is custom,

Comment: I tried to edit inbound rules like specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html but it does not work still!

Comment: Are you able to connect with psql? Or maybe this question is already outdated? Did you found solution?

Comment: @Alex Yu I still have not found the solution and yes the problem exists with psql too! I am unable to connect with that too

Comment: @SamyakGupta First you need to ensure that connection is possble in principle. Use `psql` for that. Contact Amazon support if you can't. Then proceed to django

Comment: If you're still struggling check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837806/cant-connect-to-rds-instance-from-ec2-instance

Answer (score 2):

In the VPC security group go to inbound settings create a new rule with the `Postgres` connection type, not HTTP and make it available from every.

Note: don't forget to make accessibility to the database to be public.

[image: inbound rule example]